# Add a second master node for high availabity in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was able to follow the documentation and get a kubernetes cluster up. But I would like to add a second master node I tried this on the second node  but seeing an error

```
[root@kubemaster02 ~]# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise- 
address=10.122.161.XX --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --kubernetes- 
version=v1.10.0
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.10.0
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: docker version is greater than the most 
recently validated version. Docker version: 18.03.0-ce. Max validated 
version: 17.03
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal 
with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

My question is if this is the correct way to add the second master, by doing an init ? another question I have is how to tell if the node is configured as a master or not, the following command is not showing the ROLES for some reason (may be older versions)

```
[root@master01 ~]# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                   STATUS    AGE       VERSION   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION
kubemaster01   Ready     215d      v1.8.1    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
kubemaster02   Ready     132d      v1.8.4    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
kubenode01     Ready     215d      v1.8.1    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
kubenode02     Ready     214d      v1.8.1    <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Here's documnetation for creating HA cluster using `kubeadm`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/

Answer (score 2):

In your case, please look what is running on the port 10250 :

```
netstat -nlp | grep 10250
```

Because your error is:

> [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use

In general, you can bootstrap additional master, and have 2 masters. Before running kubeadm on the other master, you need to first copy the K8s CA cert from  `kubemaster01`.  To do this, you have two options:

**Option 1: Copy with scp**

```
scp root@<kubemaster01-ip-address>:/etc/kubernetes/pki/* /etc/kubernetes/pki
```

**Option 2: Copy paste**

Copy the contents of `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`, `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key`, `/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key` and `/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub` and create these files manually on `kubemaster02`

[The next step is to create a Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#set-up-master-load-balancer) that sits in front of your master nodes. How you do this depends on your environment; you could, for example, leverage a cloud provider Load Balancer, or set up your own using NGINX, keepalived, or HAproxy.

For bootstrapping use the `config.yaml`:

```
cat >config.yaml <<EOF
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: MasterConfiguration
api:
  advertiseAddress: <private-ip>
etcd:
  endpoints:
 - https://<your-ectd-ip>:2379
  caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.pem
  certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/client.pem
  keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/client-key.pem
networking:
  podSubnet: <podCIDR>
apiServerCertSANs:
- <load-balancer-ip>  
apiServerExtraArgs:
  apiserver-count: "2"
EOF
```

Ensure that the following placeholders are replaced:

- `your-ectd-ip` the IP address your etcd
- `private-ip` it with the private IPv4 of the master server.
- `<podCIDR>` with your Pod CIDR
- `load-balancer-ip` endpoint to connect your masters

then you can run the command:

```
kubeadm init --config=config.yaml
```

and bootstrap the masters.

But if you really want a HA cluster please follow the documentation's minimal requirements and use 3 nodes for masters. They create these requirements for  etcd quorum. On every master node they run the etcd which works very close to masters.