# How to convert a Kubernetes non-HA control plane into an HA control plane?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

What is the best way to convert a kubernetes non-HA control plane into an HA control plane?

I have started with my cluster as a non-HA control plane - one master node and several worker nodes. The cluster is already running with a lots of services.

Now I would like to add additional master nodes to convert my cluster into a HA control plane. I have setup and configured a load balancer.
But I did not figure out how I can change the -control-plane-endpoint to my load balancer IP address for my existing master node.

Calling kubeadm results in the following error:

```
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "my-load-balancer:6443" --upload-certs
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: hugetlb
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-6443]: Port 6443 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml already exists
    [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
    [ERROR Port-2379]: Port 2379 is in use
    [ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
    [ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

The error message seems to be clear as my master is already running.
Is there a way how I can easily tell my existing master node to use the new load balancer to run as a HA control plane?

Comment: You wanted use kubeadm init on already working kubeadm master? Could you provide all steps you have done? Did you check [Kubeadm HA documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/) ?

Comment: ok, I understand that I need to run the command on my 2nd master. But I did not understand which parameters I should use so that my 2nd master joins the 1st master. I have already setup a load balancer. But how should the command look like? I find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887597/add-a-second-master-node-for-high-availabity-in-kubernetes) but the object 'MasterConfiguration' seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Best solution in my opinion

The best approach to `convert` a **non-HA** control plane to an **HA** control plane is to create a completely new **HA** control plane and after that to migrate all your applications there.

### Possible solution

Below I will try to help you to achieve your goal but **I do not recommend using this procedure on any cluster that will ever be considered as production cluster.** It work for my scenario, it also might help you.

#### Update the kube-apiserver certificate

First of all, **kube-apiserver** uses a `certificate` to encrypt control plane traffic and this `certificate` have something known as **SAN** (Subject Alternative Name).
SAN is a list of IP addresses that you will use to access the API, so you need to add there IP address of your `LoadBalancer` and probably the `hostname` of your `LB` as well.

To do that, you have to get `kubeadm` configuration e.g. using command:

```
   $ kubeadm config view > kubeadm-config.yaml
```

and then add `certSANs` to `kubeadm-config.yaml` config file under `apiServer` section, it should looks like below example: (you may also need to add `controlPlaneEndpoint` to point to your `LB`).

```
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - "192.168.0.2" # your LB address
  - "loadbalancer" # your LB hostname
  extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
    ...
 controlPlaneEndpoint: "loadbalancer" # your LB DNS name or DNS CNAME
    ...
```

Now you can update `kube-apiserver` cert using:
**BUT please remember** you must first delete/move your old `kube-apiserver` cert and key from `/etc/kubernetes/pki/` !

$ kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config kubeadm-config.yaml.

Finally restart your `kube-apiserver`.

#### Update the kubelet, the scheduler and the controller manager kubeconfig files

Next step is to update the `kubelet`, `scheduler` and `controller manager` to communicate with the `kube-apiserver` using `LoadBalancer`.
All three of these components use standard kubeconfig files:
`/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`, `/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf`, `/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf` to communicate with `kube-apiserver`.
The only thing to do is to edit the `server:` line to point to `LB` instead of `kube-apiserver` directly and then restart these components.

The `kubelet` is `systemd` service so to restart it use:

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

the `controller manager` and `schedulers` are deployed as pods.

#### Update the kube-proxy kubeconfig files

Next it is time to update `kubeconfig` file for `kube-proxy` and same as before - the only thing to do is to edit the `server:` line to point to `LoadBalancer` instead of `kube-apiserver` directly.

This `kubeconfig` is in fact a `configmap`, so you can edit it directly using:

```
$ kubectl edit cm kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

or first save it as manifest file:

```
$ kubectl get cm kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml > kube-proxy.yml
```

and then apply changes.

**Don't forget** to restart `kube-proxy` after these changes.

#### Update the kubeadm-config configmap

At the end upload new `kubeadm-config` `configmap` (with `certSANs` and `controlPlaneEndpoint` entries) to the cluster, it's especially important when you want to add new node to the cluster.

```
$ kubeadm config upload from-file --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

if command above doesn't work, try this:

```
$ kubeadm upgrade apply --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

Comment: Just completed a conversion using this answer (super helpful!) - one thing to add is to update the `cluster-info` configmap in the `kube-public` namespace to update the server field to point at the load balancer too, or new kubelets will still use the original single master IP direct. (see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1955).

Comment: Good docs on the subject here -> https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/08/12/converting-kubernetes-to-ha-control-plane/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @Ralph and I used an HAProxy on each node of my cluster, It worked for me and I'd like to share my full process with you.
If it is useful for you… But I'd like to have your opinion for improving my solution.

## The very poor man high availability

### Disclaimer

This is not a production ready solution.
It is just a proof of concept.
It works for me. But I don't know if it will work for you. Remember that you are responsible for your own actions and backups are your friends.

### Introduction

I have a Kubernetes v1.29.1 cluster running 8 nodes.
2 nodes have the control-plane role.
Cilium is the CNI, and Cilium replaces kube-proxy.
On this 2 control-plane nodes I removed the NoSchedule taint for using them also as worker.
ETCD replicates correctly beetween the 2 control planes. But it is not a high availability Kubernetes cluster.
If the control-plane node fails, the cluster is not available anymore. Because on each node, the kubelet is configured to use the first control-plane node as API server.
So, if the first control-plane node fails, the kubelet can't reach the API server anymore.
I want to add a high availability layer to my cluster.

### My proposed solution

I cannot use a load balancer in front of the 2 control-plane nodes. Because I don't have any more nodes.
So, I decided to use HAProxy on each node.
First I edited the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml file on each control-plane node for adding a `--bind-address` option because currently it listens on `:::6443`.
Then I restarted the kubelet service on the two control-planes.
I installed HAProxy on each node and I created the following configuration file:

```ini
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend kubernetes-api
    bind 127.43.43.43:6443
    default_backend kubernetes-backend

backend kubernetes-backend
    balance roundrobin
    server master1 10.254.0.4:6443 check check-ssl verify none
    server master2 192.168.2.8:6443 check check-ssl verify none
```

It will listen on 127.43.43.43:6443 and redirect the traffic to the first control-plane node or the second one if the first is not available.
On /etc/hosts I added the following line:

```bash
127.43.43.43 k8s-api k8s-api.private
```

So, I can use k8s-api as API server address.
I validated my setup by running the following command on each node:

```bash
curl -k https://k8s-api.private:6443
```

On each node a control-plane answers to the curl request.
I enabled the HAProxy service on each node and force it to start before the kubelet service. The idea is to add `Before=kubelet.service` in the `[Install]` section. I used the following command but it probably needs to be adapted to your distribution:

```bash
sudo sed -i 's/After=network-online.target\(.*\)$/After=network-online.target\1\nBefore=kubelet.service/' /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/haproxy.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now haproxy
```

### Using kubeadm for regenerating the kube-api certificate

I want to add my poor man high availability cluster to the kube-apiserver certificate SANs.
So I recovered the kubeadm configuration file:

```bash
kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o jsonpath='{.data.ClusterConfiguration}' > kubeadm-config.yaml
```

Now I added to the kubeadm configuration file the following lines:

```yaml
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - master1.private
  - master1
  - master2.private
  - master2
  - k8s-api
  - k8s-api.private
  - 10.254.0.4   # IP of the first control-plane node
  - 192.168.2.8  # IP of the second control-plane node
  - 127.43.43.43 # IP of the HAProxy
```

And I ran the following command:

```bash
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config kubeadm-config.yaml --dry-run
```

Everything seems to be ok. So I renamed the current certificate and key files on each control-plane node:

```bash
sudo mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt.old
sudo mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key.old
```

Now I issue a new certificate and key on each control-plane node:

```bash
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

I restarted the kubelet service on each control-plane node. With the command:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

I edited the kubeadm-config ConfigMap using the following command:

```bash
kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config
```

I added the previous certSANs to the kubeadm configuration ConfigMap.

### Edit the kubelet configuration

#### On the worker nodes

I edited the /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf file on each node for editing the following lines:

```yaml
    server: https://k8s-api.private:6443
```

finally I restarted the kubelet service on each worker node using the following command:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

#### On the control-plane nodes

I edited the /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf, /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf, /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf, /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf and /etc/kubernetes/super-admin.conf files on each node for editing the following lines:

```yaml
    server: https://k8s-api.private:6443
```

finally I restarted the kubelet service on each control-plane node using the following command:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

### Test the cluster

I ran the following command on each node:

```bash
kubectl get nodes -o wide
kubectl get pods -A -o wide
```

Everything seems to be ok.

### Future work

Any improvement is welcome.