# How to change control-plane-endpoint option in a live cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a cluster (on premise) as proof of concept, using this command:

`sudo kubeadm init --upload-certs --pod-network-cidr=x.x.x.x/16 --control-plane-endpoint=x.x.x.x.nip.io`

Now, i need to change the endpoint from `x.x.x.x.nip.io` to `somename.example.com`. How can i do this?

---

Kubeadm version: `&version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.4", GitCommit:"e6c093d87ea4cbb530a7b2ae91e54c0842d8308a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-16T12:36:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: Which version of `kubeadm` is used? As a short answer + going through documentation, it's easier to create a new cluster. However you can use as a base [another verified answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65565377/15537201) - idea is very similar with required steps.

Comment: I added the `kubeadm` version in question. I'll have a look in the link, thanks.

Comment: Have you move managed to move it forward?

Comment: No solution. I'll create a new cluster, as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting an answer as a community wiki out of comments, feel free to edit and expand.

---

Based on the documentation and [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505137/how-to-convert-a-kubernetes-non-ha-control-plane-into-an-ha-control-plane/65565377#65565377) (which is about switching from simple to high availability cluster and it has steps about adding `--control-plane-endpoint`), there's no easy/straight-forward solution to make it.

Considering risks and difficulty it's easier to create another cluster with a correct setup and migrate all workflows there.